# How to list down vertices passed in Floyd-Warshall algorithm

Tags: java, recursion, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I can't seem to figure out a way to list down the vertices passed as my algorithm (floyd-warshall) computes for the shortest path. I've been told that I would have to use recursion, but I don't know how to use recursion. Please give pseudocode/examples, greatly appreciated!

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Main{
        public static final int INF = 9999999;
        public static int[][] path;
        public static int[] tax;
        public static void main(String[] adsf){
            Scanner pp = new Scanner(System.in);
            int testCases = pp.nextInt();
            pp.nextLine();
            pp.nextLine();
            while(testCases-- >0){
                String[] s1 = pp.nextLine().split(" ");
                int size = s1.length;
                path = new int[size][size];
                for(int i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
                    Arrays.fill(path[i],INF);
                tax = new int[size];
                for(int j = 0; j < path[0].length; j++){
                    path[0][j] = Integer.parseInt(s1[j]);
                    if(path[0][j]==-1)path[0][j]=INF;
                }
                for(int i = 1; i < path.length;i++){
                    s1 = pp.nextLine().split(" ");
                    for(int j = 0; j < path[0].length; j++){
                        path[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(s1[j]);
                        if(path[i][j]==-1)path[i][j]=INF;
                    }
                }
                for(int k=0; k<tax.length;k++){
                    tax[k] = pp.nextInt();
                } pp.nextLine();    
                sssp();
                }
                int x,y;
                while(pp.hasNextInt()){
                    x=pp.nextInt();
                    y=pp.nextInt();
                    int cost = path[x-1][y-1];
                    System.out.println((x-1)+" "+(y-1)+" "+cost);
                }
            }
        }
        public static void sssp(){
            for(int k=0;k<path.length;k++){
                for(int i=0;i<path.length;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<path.length;j++){
                        path[i][j] = Math.min(path[i][j],path[i][k]+path[k][j]);
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: More like something to prepare myself for a test? A reviewer? It might come up tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use recursion for path reconstruction (in fact, you never *have to* use recursion in Java, it just happens to be a lot more convenient to use it to solve certain problems, including this one).

In order to be able to figure out the shortest path in addition to the length, you need a second 2D array that stores successors of your node in the path. Take a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction), the array I am talking about is called `next` in their pseudocode.

Recall that the logic of the algorithm goes as follows: "if you can get from `i` to `j` through `k` faster than going from `i` to `j` through any previously discovered path, then use the path though `k` as your current shortest path". Now all you need to do is to store the decision to go through `k` in some other array, like this:

```
if (path[i][k] + path[k][j] < path[i][j]) {
    path[i][j] = path[i][k]+path[k][j];
    next[i][j] = k;
}
```

Once Floyd-Warshal finishes, you can reconstruct the path from `i` to `j` by first reconstructing the path from `i` to `k` and then from `k` to `j`.

```
String GetPath (int i, int j) {
    if (path[i][j] == INF) return "no path";
    int intermediate = next[i][j];
    if (intermediate < 0) return " ";
    return GetPath(i,intermediate) + intermediate + GetPath(intermediate,j);
}
```

Comment: AHAHAHA. Omg. Why didn't I think of that? Probably I spent much time trying to learn recursion the past hour. Haha. They've taught us recursion, but I never really felt comfortable using it (horrible, horrible debugging is pretty discouraging). Thanks a lot! Hmm, I'll accept your answer in a minute. Stackoverflow won't let me just yet!

Comment: Oh, so that's the recursion they meant. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Should it be next[i][j] = next[i][k], when there is no direct path from i to k or the shortest path from i to k is not i->k?